# How do I insert the cursor back into the document after using find?

Tags: find, sublimetext2, keyboard-shortcuts

When using *Find* in Sublime Text 2, the insert cursor remains in the *Find* field.

I would like to be able to insert the cursor in the document after with a keyboard shortcut (using Mac.) How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'ts easy. When you are done you have to press <kbd>Esc</kbd>

Comment: Very easy. Thank you. :)